# Where can I find libLerc.so.4 library for CentOS 7?

Tags: conda, centos7, gdal

While working from terminal in conda environment:

```
gdalinfo filename
```

Error is:

```
Gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries:
  libLerc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

GDAL is installed with conda.
There is no library like that.
On CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

GDAL version is 3.5.3.

Here: https://pkgs.org/search/?q=Raster%20Compression
I can't find any package like liblerc to install
What package should be installed to fix this?

Comment: If you install gdal with [nix](https://nixos.org/) instead of conda, it installs a dependency named `lerc` ("Limited Error Raster Compression") built from https://github.com/esri/lerc, which provides libLerc.

Comment: That said, questions asking for us to find an off-site resource are explicitly, categorically off-topic on Stack Overflow. See #3 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing library errors are [often due to improperly mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Installing `gdal` in a fresh environment with `conda-forge` channel prioritized works just fine. E.g.,

```bash
$ mamba create -n foo -c conda-forge gdal
$ mamba activate foo
(foo) $ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.6.2, released 2023/01/02
```

We can also track down the package that normally provides the file OP is missing using `conda package --which`:

```bash
(foo) $ conda package --which ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libLerc.so.4
/opt/conda/envs/foo/lib/libLerc.so.4       conda-forge/linux-64::lerc-4.0.0-h27087fc_0
```

That is, the Conda Forge package `lerc` installs this file.